# Importing a Go module from a private git repo using ssh

Tags: git, go, ssh

I have a Go module in a private git repo on my homelab network (*not* on GitHub) which I access using the SSH protocol ie.

```
origin ssh://<user>@<servername>.local/var/git_repos/tftp.git
```

I now want to `go get` this module into another project. How do I do this?

The command `go get ssh://<user>@<servername>.local/var/git_repos/tftp` returns the error

```
go: ssh:/<user>@<servername>.local/var/git_repos/tftp: malformed module path "ssh:/<user>": invalid char ':'
```

while the command `go get <servername>.local/var/git_repos/tftp` returns

```
go: unrecognized import path "<servername>.local/var/git_repos/tftp": https fetch: Get "https://<servername>.local/var/git_repos/tftp?go-get=1": dial tcp: lookup <servername>.local on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving
```

My `.gitconfig` file contains the clause

```
[url "ssh://dave@prometheus.local/"]
    insteadOf = https://prometheus.local/
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to Go and relatively new to Git. I think I've done this successfully before, but I may be mistaken as I cannot find my sample code.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to specify the protocol you're using for go get in the go get command so it should be local/var/git_repos/tftp. The protocol and credential part should be set up by your git. I recommend you read this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-a-private-go-module-in-your-own-project

Comment: By default, git tries to use https to access the repository. My git host is not set up to serve repositories over https, only over ssh.

Comment: You can change your git config to use ssh instead of https in~/.gitconfig

Comment: I've added the relevant clause from my `.gitconfig` file to my original post. It hasn't helped.